# What are link arrays?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, mergesort

Could someone explain the logic behind link arrays (i.e. in merge sort using link arrays)? Like why are we using them and how does it work?

I tried understanding the code here : [Merge sort variant: using link array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27086267/merge-sort-variant-using-link-array?newreg=f19bc01e12214897a93e826e026d3531)

But couldn't understand the logic behind it.

Answer (score 1):

As used in the question, it's a variation of a single linked list where data is kept in one array, and indexes to next element are kept in a second array.

The wiki article includes this variation in a combination of it's linked list (arrays of nodes) and parallel array articles (where the indexes are kept in a separate array):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Linked_lists_using_arrays_of_nodes

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_array

In the question's code, a[] contains the data, link[] contains indexes to next element of a[], and link[0] is used as the head index, which contains the index to the first element of a[]. In the question's code a[0] is not used, so for n elements both array sizes are n+1.

In my answers to that question, I used a separate variable for the head index outside of link[], so that both array sizes are n, similar to the wiki article, which calls it listHead.

The end result is similar to a single linked list, insertion or deletion only requires changing two indexes in link[] (one of them could be listHead), rather than having to rotate part of an array.

The wiki explanation for why this would be done is for programming languages that don't support pointers, references, ..., and don't support records (classes, structs, ...).